# Call a javascript file from within asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to minimize the code in the below aspx, I want to create two separate javascripts which is then called from within asp.net. The two scripts aptly named sage payments and strip payments.

Here is the code I would like to be ported into separate js files which I hope can be called from within asp.net.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="MG_CreditCard_Authenticator_1.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<head runat="server">
    <title>Default</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server"  >
            <div id="topLevel" runat="server" margin="100px">
                <asp:Label id="InvoiceLable" runat="server" Text="Invoice" />
                <asp:TextBox id="InvoiceTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
            </div>

            <div id="secondTopLevel" runat="server" >
                <asp:Label id="DateLabel" runat="server" Text="Date"/>
                <asp:TextBox id="DateTextBox" runat="server"/>
            </div>
            <div id="thirdTopLevel" runat="server">
                <asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Finish" OnClick="button1Clicked" />
            </div>
            <div id="form2" runat="server">

                <asp:TextBox id="postInflow" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="400px" ReadOnly="true" TextMode="MultiLine" />

                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.sagepayments.net/pay/1.0.2/js/pay.min.js"></script>



                <!--    SAGE PAYMENT PROCESSOR          -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        PayJS(['PayJS/UI'], // loading the UI module...
                        function($UI) { // ... and assigning it to a variable
                            $UI.Initialize({
                                elementId: "paymentButton",
                                // identifiers (no keys!):
                                clientId: "myClientId", // https://developer.sagepayments.com/user/register
                                merchantId: "999999999997",
                                // auth, covered later:
                                authKey: "ABCD==",
                                salt: "DEFG==",
                                // config:
                                requestType: "payment", // or "vault" to tokenize a card for later
                                amount: "1.00",
                                orderNumber: "Invoice12345",
                                // convenience:
                                addFakeData: true,
                            });
                        });
                    </script>




            <div id="Sage">
            <button id="paymentButton" type="button" onclick="ACHauth" runat="server">
                    Sage Pay
                </button> 

                </div>

            <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>


                <div id="shop">

                    <button id="buttonCheckout" type="button" Text="Pay2" runat="server">Stripe Pay</button>

                </div>

                                <!--    STRIPE PAYMENT PROCESSOR          -->

                <script>
                    var checkoutHandler = StripeCheckout.configure({key: "pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh",locale: "auto"});


                    var button = document.getElementById("buttonCheckout");
                    button.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
                    checkoutHandler.open({name: "Sample Store",description: "Example Purchase",token: handleToken});
                    });


                    function handleToken(token) {
                        fetch("/charge", {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                        body: JSON.stringify(token)
                      })
                      .then(output => {
                        if (output.status === "succeeded")
                          document.getElementById("shop").innerHTML = "<p>Purhcase complete!</p>";
                      })
                    }
                </script>




            </div>



    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your JavaScript code out into the smaller appropriate files, then include in your aspx markup, something like this.

```
<script src="controls/js/request.js"></script>
```

At run time, the code in "controls/js/request.js" will be embedded.

Comment: does src required the absolute path where the file is located?

Comment: When I do that and hit the button, I get nothing happening I even tried using absolute path but still could't get it working

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<script>` tag at the end of body tag.
eg. `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/javascript1.js"></script>`

here, put your script code in `javascript1.js` which should be under `script` folder(which you can create) of your project.

`src` can be absolute or relative path, but better to use relative path.